Show data label in bar chart
Using bar charts in Scilab is there any straight way or workaround to show the data labels next to the bars?
Scilab chart:

example chart with data labels I would like to achieve in Scilab charts. I did not find any option but there might be a workaround?


Here is a commented example similar to your case, with grouped bars:
clf
[x, y] = ([1 2 5], [1  -5 6;3 -2 7;4  -3 8]);
h = bar(x, y);
xgrid(color("grey50"))

txy = h.children.data;  // get bars raw coordinates
// tune x coordinates inside groups
txy(:,1) = txy(:,1) + h.children.x_shift'(:);

// get Text height to tune y coordinates according to labels above vs below bars
th = xstringl(1,1,"8")(4);
    
// Make formated labels
ylab = msprintf("%4.1f\n",txy(:,2))' ;

// Display labels at tuned y
t = xstring(txy(:,1), txy(:,2) + th*((txy(:,2)>=0)-0.5), ylab);
// Center them on their required position.
//   This makes rendered positions robust against figure resizing
t.children.text_box_mode = "centered";

// reframe the plot to show the value for the highest bar
replot

Result:

